# How can I map this range in a function?

Tags: functions

I have a range of input values, from 0 to 1.

I want a function like this:

```
1° - values from 0 to 0.24=> output 0
2° - values from 0.25 to 0.50=> output 1
3° - values from 0.51 to 1=> output 0
```

A sort of Square signal. Can you help me?

Comment: What do you want to output given the input $0.25$?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question ;)

Comment: And what if the input is 0.501?! ;)

Comment: @Oliver: of course 1 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?
$$f(x) = \chi_{[0.25;05]}(x) $$

---

Or, according to the comment in a different answer:

$$ f(x) = \operatorname{IfL}(0.25;x)\cdot \operatorname{IfL}(x;0.5)$$

Comment: Maybe you should rather use $\operatorname{IfLE}$ because your function will return 0 if x = 0.25 or x = 0.5 whereas it should return 1.

Comment: It works perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a function as piecewise as you have there, if we call your function $f(x)$, we can define it as:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x \in [0,0.25) \\ 1 & x \in [0.25,0.5) \\ 0 & x \in [0.5,1]\end{cases}$$

Where $x\in[a,b)$ means $a \leq x \lt b$.

Comment: Can't use this "syntax". I have to write it as "command line/math expression" in a software. Such as y= Input*0.25 + 0.25...

Comment: Can you use boolean logic, for instance, could you have `y = (0.25 <= Input && Input < 0.5)`?

Comment: No, can't use boolean logic. This is what I can use: http://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/plugins/Fruity%20Formula%20Controller.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use logical operators, this should work for $x \neq 0.25, 0.5$ :

Let $P(x) := -x^2 + \frac{3}{4}x - \frac{1}{8}$.

And output  $\displaystyle \frac{max(P(x), 0)}{P(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put this in a software, what you could write is something like

IF(X.GE.0.0.AND.X.LT.0.25) THEN
Y = 0.0
ELSE IF(X.LE.0.5) THEN
Y = 1.0
ELSE IF(X.LE.1.0) THEN
Y = 0.0
END IF

This does not cover the cases where X < 0 or X > 1.